# I can not navigate to the next page in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am trying to navigate form one page to another page depends upon the login.

If already user logged in, Welcome page should open. Else Log in Page should open.

I am trying like this. The Splash Page is the start up page.

This is a Splash Screen Xaml.cs:

```
namespace NewExample.Views
{
    public partial class SplashPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public SplashPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new SplashPageViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

This is Splash Screen View Model: Here I am check the user already logged in or not.

```
namespace NewExample.ViewModel
{
    public class SplashPageViewModel
    {
        public static bool isLogin = false;

        public SplashPageViewModel()
        {
            var rootFrame = (App.Current as App).RootFrame;
            if (isLogin)
                rootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/WelcomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                rootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/LoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not working. The Splash Page only showing. This is not navigating to another page. Please help me to resolve this problem.

If I write the codes in Splash Page Xaml.cs, it's working.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var rootFrame = (App.Current as App).RootFrame;
            if (isLogin)
                rootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/WelcomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                rootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/LoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

But I want to use this in `ViewModel`.

Comment: are sure that the path given to navigate is correct? For the if condition try giving if(isLogin == false) and see.

Comment: My path is correct. If I debug the program the controls are going correct way. So`if(isLogin)` is correct.

Comment: If you want to do in your View Model I think you sould wrap the call to Navigate with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to pass the control to UI thread.

Comment: ya.. You are right @Ivan..!! Now i got the idea..!! Thank you..

Comment: @Vijay you are welcome! I modified my answer with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right what you're trying to accomplish - here is a complete guide  at [nokia.developer](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_dynamically_set_the_application_start_page_on_Windows_Phone) portal.

And if you want to perform UI actions from a ViewModel wrap them with the call to [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx) .

Comment: Yes.. This what i want. But i want to write it in ViewModel.